# Edit angular material's date-picker template to add arrows for quick navigation

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material's [datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) inside my page, and was wondering whether it would be possible instead of dragging up and down to quickly move between months, to add two arrows that would move to the next/previous month similar to other more traditional date-pickers.

Is this possible, and if yes how should I go on about doing it.

Comment: If waiting a few weeks is a choice for you, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4251) with your requirements linked to the `1.0.0-rc7`  release. Theorically, it has to be released soon...

Comment: @troig rc7 is out, but the change was not made. This practically means that atm ngMaterial does not have a datepicker yet.

Comment: @deam44 you're right. Further, they have moved to this issue to post-1.0  instead 1.0-rc8..Bad news :(